# Google Sheets script to ignore or include specific sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getName" of null. I have used a script to replace the formulas of the active sheet with the cell values. However, I don't want to accidentally run this on a few sheets, so I want to be able to exclude or include only specific sheets. I have been following another  post and came up with this, and now I have the error:

```
function freezeValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  //loop through all sheets and get name to see if it includes specific string
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    var name = sheet.getName();
    if (name.includes("String_00")) {
      //get active sheet and replace range with values
      var sheetActive = ss.getActiveSheet();  
      var range = sheetActive.getRange("A1:Z50");
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
    } else {
      continue;
      //skip over all those that don't meet the condition
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Trying this:

```
function freezeValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  //loop through all sheets and get name to see if it includes specific string
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    //var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    var name = sheets[i].getName().toString();
    if (name.indexOf("String_00") > -1) {
      //get active sheet and replace range with values
      //var sheetActive = ss.getActiveSheet();  
      var range = sheets.getRange("A1:Z50");
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
    } else {
      continue;
      //skip over all those that don't meet the condition
    }
  }
}
```

But now it doesn't do anything. using .include was giving me an error, so I moved over to .indexOf() > -1. Does not freeze data as expected for any sheet, regardless of name.

Comment: The clears the error, but then I get another error, "TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object Sheetname." Googling, I found that includes has been recommended to be replaced with indexOf()>-1 and convert the name to a string. So I tried that, and it seems to allow all sheets to be frozen, and isn't stopping for those that do not contain that string...

Comment: I was using getActiveSheet so that it only freezes the one I have pulled up on the UI. I don't think I call for ActiveSheet anywhere else, just ActiveSpreadsheet which is the entire doc, not the individual tab, right?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with 2 solutions for this, sort of started from the drawing board. One creates an array, a sort of blacklist, and then if the sheet name contains any item in the blacklist, then it returns and doesn't execute the replacement. The second solution searches for a pattern in the sheet name and only then continues on to the replacement. Both accomplish what I was trying to do. I think the code I found was a bit buggy and was a bit complicated for what I was doing. I didn't need to loop through all sheet names, just check the sheet name against given variables.  Anyway, here  they are:

This one creates the array blacklist of pages not to edit:

```
function freezeValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'];
  var sheetActive = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  if (sheets.indexOf(sheetActive.getName()) > -1) return;
  var range = sheetActive.getRange("A1:Z50");
    range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

This one only searches for specific text in the sheet name before proceeding with the replacement.

```
function freezeValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetActive = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var name = sheetActive.getName()
  if (name.indexOf("String_00") > -1) {
    var range = sheetActive.getRange("A1:Z50");
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a method to use sheet index value so if you want to skip the first 4 sheets, you can probably do that as well, so it doesn't call on names at all.

UPDATE

```
function freezeValues2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetActive = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheetActive.getIndex() > 4) {
    var range = sheetActive.getRange("A1:Z50");
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed. It would look like
`if (sheetActive.getIndex() > 4) ` or whatever range you want to ignore. This would replace the sheets array or the name variable, and replace the if line.